# Jframe resize on right

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a little problem with `JFrame` resize. I need to resize a frame when I push a button but I need to take visible the right side of frame.

For default when I resize some `JFrame` ho show me the left size.

```
    JButton btnX = new JButton("");
    btnX.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int x = ((Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width/2)-221);
            int y = (0);
            if(contr==0){
                //frmAsda.setBounds(x, y, 442, 45);
                frmAsda.setBounds(x, y, 100, 170);
                contr=1;
                frmAsda.setBackground(new Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.0f));

            } else if (contr==1){
                //frmAsda.setBounds(x, y, 442, 216);
                 frmAsda.setBounds(x, y, 442, 170);
                contr=0;
                frmAsda.setBackground(new Color(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.7f));

            }
        }
    });
```

from this frame

[image]

to this:

[image]

Comment: Upload the image to some image sharing site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your Panel into JScrollPane and make ScrollBars not visible. 
On resize just scroll right.